# In the isosceles triangle, the two squares (white) both have an area of four. Find the area of the shaded.

Tags: area

In the isosceles triangle below, the two squares (white) both have an area
of four. Find the area of the shaded.[image]

According to my answer key, the answer is $9\sqrt{2}$ square units. How can I show the solution through the parallel line theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how you would answer this using theorems about parallel lines.
Here's a sketch of a solution using similar triangles.

Let $x$ be the distance from the top of the triangle to the 
middle of the top edge of the top most white square.
Let $y$ be the distance from the top of the triangle to the
centre of the lower white square.
By similar triangles we have $x / 1 = y/ \sqrt{2}$.
Since $y = x + 2 + \sqrt{2}$, solving gives $x = 4 + 3 \sqrt{2}$.
So the height of the whole is   isosceles triangle is $h = 6 + 5\sqrt{2}$.

Again by similar triangles we can determine that the length of the base is $b = h(2/x)$.
And so the area of the whole isoceles triangle is  $bh/2 = h^2/x = 8 + 9\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I think since the bases of the two triangles you mentioned are parallel is why you can conclude they are similar triangles. I think this might be a theorem. http://www.malinc.se/math/geometry/similartrianglesen.php  See Corollary of Proportionality Theorem

Answer (score 1):

Since the squares have area $4$, they have side $2$.

WLOG suppose the bottom-most point on the tilted square has coordinates $(0,0)$. Then the coordinates of the right side of the bottom square are $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ and the coordinates of the upper-rightmost points on the second square are $(1,2+\sqrt{2})$. So the line going through them is $y=\left(-4-3 \sqrt{2}\right) x+5 \sqrt{2}+6$. Then the height of the triangle is $6+5\sqrt{2}$ and its base is $\frac{2 \left(6+5 \sqrt{2}\right)}{4+3 \sqrt{2}}$, which imply its area is $8+9\sqrt{2}$. Subtracting the area of the squares gives the remaining area as $9\sqrt{2}$, as claimed.